# Fill right in OpenOffice/LibreOffice

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I'm using LibreOffice Calc for an application where it's necessary for me to fill right. I know that fill down is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, but is there a way to fill across to the right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out there's no hot-key for it (by default anyway). But you can get it by going to menu *Edit* → *Fill* → *Right*.

In LibreOffice version 5 it is menu *Sheets* → *Fill Cells*.

Comment: As of LO version 5 it is found in `Sheets > Fill Cells`.